Proving $\frac{1}{ab+a+2}+\frac{1}{bc+b+2}+\frac{1}{ca+c+2}\le 3/4, abc=1$
Let $F=\frac{1}{ab+a+2}+\frac{1}{bc+b+2}+\frac{1}{ca+c+2}; a,b,c>0,abc=1.$
Let $a=x/y,b=y/z,c=z/x$ and  then
$$F=\frac{yz}{xy+zx+2yz}+\frac{zx}{xy+yz+2zx}+\frac{xy}{yz+xz+2xy}
.$$
Letting $xy+yz+zx=s$, we can write
$$
F=\frac{yz}{s+yz}+\frac{zx}{s+zx}+\frac{xy}{s+xy} = 3-s\left[\frac{1}{s+yz}+\frac{1}{s+zx}+\frac{1}{s+xy}\right].$$
$$\implies \frac{3-F}{s}=\left[\frac{1}{s+yz}+\frac{1}{s+zx}+\frac{1}{s+xy}\right].$$
Using AM-HM, we get
$$\frac{3-F}{s}\ge \frac{9}{4s}\implies F \le \frac{3}{4}.$$
The question is how else this inequality be proved?


Your solution is nice, and the substitution is the process of general proof of inequality w/ $abc=1.$ 2) Not a perfect answer, but maybe using a CS and AM-GM will give you another solution method, or the same one you wrote.


Fix $s$, let $yz = p, zx = q, xy = r$, and we have $ \sum s/(s+p) = \sum s^2/(s^2+ps) \geq (s+s+s)^2/(3s^2+s^2) = 9/4 $ by CS.
